# printf prints to a binary file in c

Tags: c, file-io, printf

I have a binary file that I open, modify, and close. And then I `printf` to the console.

This all works fine, but I realized just now that it's appending whatever I'm printing to the console to the end of the binary file, and it makes no difference whether or not the file is open or closed.

The same thing happens with `fprintf`.

What's going on here? Is there something I don't understand about file I/O?

Update: Here's the code:

```
FILE *out = fopen("test","wb+");
fseek(out,0,SEEK_END);
fwrite("test",1,10,out);
fwrite("test",1,10,out);
fwrite("test",1,10,out);
int pos = ftell(out);
fwrite(&pos,sizeof(int),1,out);
fclose(out);
fprintf(stdout,"%s","hello");
```

Comment: Can you post code that demonstrates this?

Comment: Yes, without code, we can't really help you.  It would also be helpful if you show us how you run your program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The calls to `fwrite()` are incorrect as they are instructing `fwrite()` to write `10` characters from a 5 character array (string literals have an implicit null character appended). This will be accessing beyond the ends of the array, resulting in undefined behaviour and is a probable cause of the strange behaviour.

Correct the `fwrite()` calls:

```
fwrite("test", 1, 4, out);
```

As per comment, if there must be 10 characters then declare an array:

```
char msg[10] = "test"; /* Unspecified elements will be null. */

fwrite(msg, 1, sizeof(msg), out);
```

Comment: Is there any way to keep the 10 characters? Like making the last 6 characters NULL?

Comment: Change `fwrite("test",1,10,out);` to be `fwrite("test\0\0\0\0\0\0",1,10,out);`.

Comment: Is that the case with malloc as well? Or do I have to `memset` the elements to null?

Comment: @Matt, that is not the case with `malloc()`. You must initialise, with `memset()` or individually. Note that `sizeof()` will not return the number of elements in a `malloc()`d array.

Comment: @hmjd That was the problem. Thank you.